# Translating “light reading” in French

Tags: vocabulaire

I am trying to translate "light reading" into French.

Definition from Collins dictionary: "reading which is not considered too demanding or intellectual"

For example a horror book is not light reading, a romantic story can be.

suggestion: lecture légère

Comment: The following suggestions are probably too seasonal for year-round use, but unless it’s from a required reading list assigned by one of your Professors, “Summer reading/reads” and “Beach reading/reads” are usually pretty light (but not necessarily of low quality), from which you could get to [“Lecture/s d'été”](http://www.lapresse.ca/arts/livres/201606/17/01-4993014-lectures-dete-des-romans-a-lire-partout.php) and [“Lecture/s de plage”](http://www.senscritique.com/liste/Lecture_de_plage_2012/89834) in French.

Answer (score 3):

Une traduction idiomatique pourrait être : *roman de gare*, on désigne sous cette appellation des romans plutôt simples à lire avec un vocabulaire des plus réduit, *de gare* parce qu'ils sont généralement vendus dans les gares.

Comment: *Roman de gare* (in English "airport novels") is not only easy to read but the term is used to depict **low quality literature**. The English "light reading" is synonym of easy reading, (lecture facile in French) it does not carry any negative appreciation on the literary qualities of the book

Answer (score 0):

You could translate it by "Romans à l'eau de rose", but keep in mind that this generally involves that the story is a romance with a traditional happy end.

Comment: *Romans à l'eau de rose* ("slushy novel" in English) usually make light reading for sure but not all light reading books are slushy novels. Light reading can be used for good literature as well.

Comment: Welcome on FrenchSE, have a [tour] to understand better how this site works. Don't forget to add some source to your answer to make it more valuable.

Answer (score 0):

On parle parfois de textes en *français simplifié*, en *français facile* ou de *lecture facile*. Ils sont classés par niveaux d'accessibilité.

Certains lecteurs peuvent aussi trouver leur bonheur dans la *littérature jeunesse*. Ceux-là sont plutôt classés par ages.

Voir par exemple: [Les textes en français simplifié, une voie pour l’enseignement de la littérature ?](http://luccolles.canalblog.com/archives/2014/07/05/30198083.html)

Comment: Je ne crois pas que "français simplifié / facile" ait un rapport avec la question.